# Specializing a templated member of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specialization of templated member function in templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773302/specialization-of-templated-member-function-in-templated-class)

```
template <class T>    
class MyClass
{
   template <int N>
   void func() {printf("unspecialized\n");}
};
template<class T>
template<>
MyClass<T>::func<0>()
{
   printf("specialzied\n");
}
```

This does not work. Is it possible to specialize a template method of an template class?

Comment: You should add the error message you get, since "does not work" really doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It cannot be done as requested. For some reason (I'm not sure about the rationale) *explicit* (i.e *full*) specialization of a member template is only allowed when the enclosing class is also *explicitly* (i.e *fully*) specialized. This requirement is explicitly spelled out in the language standard (see 14.7.3/18 in C++98, C++03 and 14.7.3/16 in C++11).

At the same time, *partial* specializations of member *class* templates are allowed, which in many cases can be used as a workaround (albeit an ugly one). But, obviously, it is only applicable to member *class* templates. When it comes to member *function* templates, an alternative solution has to be used.

For example, a possible workaround is to delegate the call to a static member of a template class and specialize the class instead (which is often recommended as a better idea than specialization of function templates http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

```
template <class T>    
class MyClass
{
   template <int N, typename DUMMY = void> struct Func {
     static void func() { printf("unspecialized\n"); }
   };

   template <typename DUMMY> struct Func<0, DUMMY> {
     static void func() { printf("specialized\n"); }
   };

   template <int N> void func() { Func<N>::func(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I found out as well - I have to specialize the containing class. Your solution with using a class for the function is maybe the best solution in my case

Comment: Do you have a reference for this requirement? I've been reading through the part(s) of the standard that look relevant (starting around §14.7.3) and haven't been able to find this requirement.

Comment: @Jerry : C++11 §14.7.3/16: "*... except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.*"

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: In C++98 and C++03 it was stated in 14.7.3/18. In C++11 it was relocated to 14.7.3.16, as **ildjarn** noted.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah, the rearrangement was what got me -- I read down a ways in the '03 standard, sort of gave up before I got to it, and decided to look in the new standard instead. I looked at some of the first paragraphs, and they seemed pretty much identical, so I more or less skipped down to about where I'd left off. Murphy still being in charge, that was around paragraph 17...

Comment: I am now convinced that c++ is broken beyond repair...

Comment: @AnT Hello. The paragraph that you mention in your answer contains the following, as quoted by ildjarn: "except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a **class** member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.". Doesn't this exception refer only to **class templates** and therefore specializing a function member template without specializing its enclosing class template should be legal? Thank you.