# Template function nested in template struct, g++ specialization error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, nested

I'm porting Windows code to Linux. So, i have a code

```
 template <typename PROPERTY,typename T_COORDINATE=am3::model::Coordinates>
  struct Provider
  {
    virtual PROPERTY GetState(am3::model::common::Point<T_COORDINATE>* point,const PROPERTY* const typeTrait)=0;
        virtual PROPERTY GetState(am3::model::common::Point<T_COORDINATE>* point)
        {
            const PROPERTY* const typeTrait_=nullptr;
            return this->GetState(point,typeTrait_);
        }
    template <typename T>
    PROPERTY GetState(am3::model::common::Point<T_COORDINATE>* point);
    template <>
    PROPERTY GetState<PROPERTY>(am3::model::common::Point<T_COORDINATE>* point)
    {
      const PROPERTY* const typeTrait_=nullptr;
      return this->GetState(point,typeTrait_);
    }
  };
```

and MSVC compiling it without problems, but
g++ show me error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘struct am3::model::contract::Provider’

I tried overload it, specialize function after struct body and more,
([Specialization of templated member function in templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773302/specialization-of-templated-member-function-in-templated-class) etc, etc..) but I'm stuck now.
Has anyone an idea, how to do it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As the answer for the question you linked says: `You cannot specialize a member without also specializing the class`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10178791/1147772 and in general [avoid specialising function templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: I was on this page too. When I tried    "template <typename T, class Dummy = void> [...] template <class Dummy>" error was:
error: function template partial specialization ‘GetState<PROPERTY>’ is not allowed

Comment: Yep, you can't partially specialise function templates, as the linked question i posted in the previous comments suggest, you could transform that into a template class with a static function. But i'm afraid you will need to change the way it is called in the rest of the code.

Comment: It's my general problem - i can't change rest of code, because my code is only one of many libraries. But many thanks for your suggestions/