# Specialiation of template class that is member of template class

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have a specialized template class which is a member of a template class(that is not specialized per se)?

With a non-template parent class this works:

```
class owner
{
    template<int num>
    struct s
    {
        int ret() { return num; }
    };
};

template<>
struct owner::s<0>
{
    int ret() { return 0; }
};
```

But when making `owner` a template class it does not:

```
template<typename some>
class owner
{
    template<int num>
    struct s
    {
        int ret() { return num; }
    };
};

template<typename some>
struct owner<some>::s<0>
{
    int ret() { return 0; }
};
```

Searching shows that this is not possible(?) for functions, but how about classes/structs?
[Specializing a templated member of a template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178598/specializing-a-templated-member-of-a-template-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not possible. A member class template can only be specialised if all of its enclosing class templates are also specialised. Quoting C++2x (N4713) [temp.expl.spec] 17.8.3/17:

> **In an explicit specialization declaration for** a member of a class template or **a member template** that
>   appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, except that **the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its
>   enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.**

(Emphasis mine)

In some cases, you could get around this by making the nested name `s` an alias to a namespace-scope helper which can be partially specialised. Something like this:

```
template <class some, int num>
struct s_helper
{
  int ret() { return num; }
};

template<typename some>
class owner
{
    template<int num>
    using s = s_helper<some, num>;
};

template<typename some>
struct s_helper<some, 0>
{
    int ret() { return 0; }
};
```

To reduce the exposure of `s_helper`, it can of course be hidden in a suitably named internal namespace (such as `detail`).

Comment: This makes me sad as one is now required to exposes a private type to the namespace.

Comment: @AartStuurman It can of course be hidden in a suitably named namespace such as `detail`.