# template specialization for member functions in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, c++17

I have a templated class foo which has templated member function. I have a problem with the specialization of the  templated function.

```
template<typename T, int x...>
class foo_c
{
    ...
    template<int n>
    int foo() { return n; }
};
template<>
template<>
int foo_c<int,1>::foo<0>() { return 0; }
```

the above code compile but I need foo_c to be generic, when add anything to the template I get a compiler error.

Questions:

- how can I fix this?
- what are the rules that the compiler follow when exposed to specialization?

**EDIT:**

**Trying**

```
template<typename T, int x, int y>
template<>
int foo_c<T,x,y>::foo<0>() { return 0; }
```

**Error**

```
error: invalid explicit specialization before '>' token
error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
error: expected initializer before '<' token
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the error you get when you "add anything to the template"

Comment: I've edited an mcve since I'm also interested in an answer.

Comment: @YSC I rolled back your edit since OP's original implementation of `foo` is correct, so I'd like OP to provide whatever error they're actually having.

Comment: @chedynajjar Ignore YSC. Add your error and example.

Comment: @Barry I fear the error message would help less than a concise & precise question; but I could be wrong. Will see.

Comment: Related to [specialization-of-templated-member-function-in-templated-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773302/specialization-of-templated-member-function-in-templated-class).

Comment: Fully specialize the method (and class) is possible, but not partial specialization.

Comment: @YSC That is why I asked for an MCVE from OP - to get a concise and precise question. Now that we have one, it is answerable - in this case from the dupe.

Comment: @Barry My bad; thanks for the found dup.